# Tell Flux to emit next item after async processing

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using Project Reactor with Webflux to try to read data from a message queue, then process it in chunks (eg, five at a time) and make a request to an API with each chunk. The API does not work well with high throughput, so I need to have control over how many requests are sent concurrently.

Basically, I'd like to have a WebClient call finish, then be able to tell the Flux that we're ready to process more.

I was using this code to try to emulate the desired functionality, and I'm getting results that I don't understand:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val subscriber = CustomSubscriber()

    Flux.create<Int> { sink ->
        sink.onRequest {
            sink.next(1)
        }
    }
        .doOnNext {
            println("hit first next with $it")
        }
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // Mock WebClient call
        .doOnNext {
            println("before request")
            subscriber.request(1)
            println("after request")
        }
        .subscribeWith(subscriber)

    Thread.sleep(10000)
}

class CustomSubscriber : BaseSubscriber<Int>() {
    override fun hookOnSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
        subscription.request(1)
    }
}
```

The output of this code is

```
hit first next with 1
before request
after request
```

What I was hoping for is this:

```
hit first next with 1 // one second passes
before request
after request
hit first next with 1 // one second passes
before request
after request
hit first next with 1 // one second passes
before request
after request
hit first next with 1 // one second passes
before request
after request
```

(Infinite loop)

So the request method is called, but the number is never emitted.

Oddly, when I call request in a separate Flux, I'm getting the desired behavior:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val subscriber = CustomSubscriber()
    
    Flux.create<Int> { sink ->
        sink.onRequest {
            sink.next(1)
        }
    }
        .doOnNext {
            println("hit first next with $it")
        }
        .subscribeWith(subscriber)

    Flux.range(0, 5)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
        .doOnNext { subscriber.request(1) }
        .subscribe()

    Thread.sleep(10000)
}

class CustomSubscriber : BaseSubscriber<Int>() {
    override fun hookOnSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
        subscription.request(1)
    }
}
```

So it seems like there is an issue with calling the `request` method in the `doOnNext` method of the original Flux?

I'm not married to the idea of using a `FluxSink`, that just seemed like a way to have more explicit control of the data emission.

Comment: Not odd at all `nothing happens until you subscribe` in the second example you are manyally calling `subscribe` while your first example i have no idea what you are trying to achive. Why a custom subscriber?

Comment: They're both subscribed to with the `subscribeWith` method. I created a subscriber to be able to call the `request` method. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Im not super well versed in Kotlin, so im mostly trying to understand what you are trying to achive. As i dont really understanding what it is you are trying to do. I dont know (yet) why you need implement a custom subscriber (since you are basically doing the exact same thing as the standard subscriber is doing. The second example you are actually intializing a flux containing 5 items, which means the flux will emit 5 items and call `doOnNext` 5 times.

Comment: i dont understand why you are subscribing with a custom subscriber (subscribeWith), and also calling `subscribe.request`with the same subscriber in the `doOnNext` as it makes no sense. When subscribing, the api will call the request function for you automatically. Did you read the official documentation of how these things work?

Comment: can you please show the output of how you expect it to work, as you have not included that just `Oddly, this code does work` but not HOW you expect it to work.

Comment: The main thing I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to explicitly pull elements from a Flux. I'm using the custom subscriber as it exposes the `request` method. The `BaseSubscriber` docs read: __A simple base class for a Subscriber implementation that lets the user perform a request(long) and cancel() on it directly__ - which is what I would like to do.

In the first example, the desired output would be what I posted, but repeating every second

Comment: If I just do this:
```kotlin
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).flatMap { callApi() }.subscribe()

```
the API calls will all happen concurrently. I'd like to send 3 API calls concurrently, then when they're all finished, request 3 more elements from the Flux

Comment: please update the question with the desired output, dont describe what output you are expecting. A custom subscriber is usually only needed if you need to request for items in a custom way, so when you are using `subscribeWith` you are applying your base subscriber and items start flowing in accordance to how you implemented your `subscriber` Why you are manually calling `subscriber.request` is not needed, i dont understand why you are doing that.

Comment: then i suggest you look into the `buffer` functions in the `flux` api where you can define a buffer of n items, that will emit items in accordance to a certain predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is custom subscriber, which consumes data at its own pace based on some logic. Something like this.

```
Flux.range(0, 14)
    .subscribeWith(object : Subscriber<Int> {
        
        private var count = 0
        lateinit var subscription: Subscription

        override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {

            subscription = s
            s.request(2)
        }
        override fun onNext(parameter: Int) {

            println("Before request")
            // ----- some processing
            println("After request")
            count++
            if (count >= 2) {

                println("Requesting more......")
                count = 0
                subscription.request(2)
            }
        }
        override fun onError(t: Throwable) {}
        override fun onComplete() {

            println("Done")
        }
    })
```